# How to show out of stock in configurable product's option selection Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, stock, magento2.3.2

**How to show out of stock in configurable product Magento 2.3.2**

> like the below image

https://i.ibb.co/JpKdwNx/5210046c-6f62-11e6-8db7-abda30a5c09d.png

Answer (score 0):

If the product option has no qty then it will automatically show red [/]. Its Magento **inbuilt-functionality**.